# What does %U mean in Google Chrome command on MX Linux?

Tags: bash, google-chrome

I use MX Linux 17 (Horizon) and Google Chrome browser.

When I look at its command, it states, `/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable %U`. From this I understand Chrome executes this `google-chrome-stable` file with `%U` argument.

What does `%U` stand for? Where does this come from? I look at environment variable - by `printenv` command - and there is no such name listed on it.

Comment: 1. Is `google-chrome-stable` a script file (i.e. can you open it in an editor) or a binary executable? 2. Where did you read the `/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable %U`? Is it the property of a shortcut?

Comment: Hi Micha. It's a symlink to the google-chrome script file on /opt/google/chrome/. When you RIGHT-click on the google-chrome-stable on /usr/bin/ and then choose Property, it shows in the command field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's more than likely an `Exec` for a [Desktop Entry Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s07.html).

> `%U` - A list of URLs. Each URL is passed as a separate argument to the executable program. Local files may either be passed as file: URLs or as file path.